# Service Worker: How to cache images that do not have extensions using Workbox

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, image-caching

I'm new on service worker in my page i have images without extensions **[*.jpg, *.png and etc]**  like this "`www.domain.com/api/media/a2b93f21-1acf-4e5e-9b19-6d7c68aaadc2`" which i get them from API.

*The following code work fine but not for this type of images*

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    // Cache image files.
    /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    // Use the cache if it's available.
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
        // Use a custom cache name.
        cacheName: 'image-cache',
        plugins: [
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                // Cache only 20 images.
                maxEntries: 20,
                // Cache for a maximum of a week.
                maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            })
        ],
    })
);
```

**Any suggestion ?**

Comment: Couldn't you adjust your route rule to apply to anything on the `/api/media/` directory? Do you serve anything but images out of that?

Comment: actually there is file manager to upload images and also get images by calling `media` from API, in the front we just get a `Guid` as filename.

Comment: One way to solve this problem would be to check the headers of the requested file. If the headers tell the SW that the requested entity is an image file, then cache it.

Answer (score 4):

with workbox, from the [manual](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes#cache_resources_based_on_resource_type) -

> You can use the [RequestDestination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestDestination) enumerate type of the
>   destination of the request to determine a strategy. For example, when
>   the target is  data

:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // Custom `matchCallback` function
  ({event}) => event.request.destination === 'image',
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'image',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 20,
        maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 week
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

in a plain vanilla service worker you can check the [request accept header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values)

```
if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('image') !== -1) { 
    ... stash in cache ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @denov for your time to answer, i will test it & i don't forget rate your answer.

Comment: @denov Hello, could you check this question out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117929/workbox-service-worker-maxageseconds-query